# Will users with Office 365 E3 get a license for Microsoft viva

Tags: office-365, administration, licensing, microsoft-viva

Some users inside our organization want to use the licensed version of Microsoft Viva, and they have E3 license as follow:-

[image]

So will they get a license version of Microsoft Viva, since they are E3 users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get information about Viva Licensing from the [Microsoft Viva plans and pricing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-viva/pricing) page.

Users with an E3 license will get full access to Viva Connections and partial access to Viva Learning and Viva Insights.

[image: Microsoft Viva plans and pricing]

Comment: but on this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-viva/buy?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab it mentioned that MS Viva will be included inside E3.. so the 2 links are a bit confusing ..

Comment: I think you're confusing Microsoft Viva as a product and Microsoft Viva Suite as a license. I believe what the content of that page is saying is that you need a Microsoft 365 license to purchase the Microsoft Viva Suite license.